# jQuery: find all divs with given class after a specific div, but not sibilings at same level

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my html like this:

```
<div id="d1" class="parent">
<div class="hello"></div>
<div class="hello"></div>
</div>
<div id="d2" class="parent">
<div class="ciao"></div>
<div class="hello"></div>  
</div>
<div id="d3" class="parent">
<div class="hello"></div>  
<div class="hello"></div> 
</div> 
<div id="d4" class="parent">
<div class="hello"></div>  
<div class="ciao"></div>
</div>
```

And I need to select all the divs that have "hello" class, starting from the one included in d2.

if I use this code, ti doesn't hop the next div to find the other "hello"

```
$('#2 .hello').nextAll().doSomething();
```

how do i solve this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With my limited knowledge of jQuery:

```js
$('#d2').find('.hello').parent().nextAll().addBack().children('.hello').html('changed')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1" class="parent">
  <div class="hello">1</div>
  <div class="hello">2</div>
</div>
<div id="d2" class="parent">
  <div class="ciao">3</div>
  <div class="hello">4</div>
</div>
<div id="d3" class="parent">
  <div class="hello">5</div>
  <div class="hello">6</div>
</div>
<div id="d4" class="parent">
  <div class="hello">7</div>
  <div class="ciao">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I feel like you took my comment on your question as a personal attack, apologies if I came off like so, I merely wanted point out that if there were more divs with parent class before, let's say d2, then your code will include all divs except the first one. I do not claim my code to be superior, but this code will select all divs after d2, regardless of the number of divs with parent class before d2.

Comment: Op never mentioned if there are classes more then one before d2. So i have provided a solution on that - As per the question.

Answer (score -1):

[Jquery Traversing Api Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)

I think this link may be useful.
I do not know the answer you are looking for but i might be of help.
Regards.
I Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the constructive approach! :D

Comment: Ops. No problem i will get better ( I hope) :P, And Thanks for clarification! Regards

Comment: @Alwayshelping My english is bad excuse me!